# How can I easily rank up?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I want to be rank 50 as fast as possible to call muggers on my friends.

Which missions earn the best RP?

I tried the heists but they are not reliable for various reasons :

- One time I couldn't take the plane to the airport in time.
- Another, I broke the plane.
- Another, some stranger died and finished our team lives.
- In another heist, I got shot down.
- And I fell down and died.

I need an easy to play, fast and popular mission for GTA Online, which gives a lot of RP and money.

As you know, you can't open every mission on all ranks. I am rank 8 at the moment. However my latest rank can be seen [here](http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/games/gtav/pc/career/overview/gtaonline) (My rank is written under "GTA Online"). But, because this might be a solution for other people, please include parts like "Best missions between ranks 0-3" and "... 3-5" and "... 5-10" etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vote  and go for Survival Missions. They are for higher level (I think 15). But you can participate with lower level. There you got between 3000 and 6000 rp. Depends on your skill. And do the missions you get through sms. You can call npcs and asks for Missions. Races are good if you're good and a lot of people are participating, because the reward gets more with more people. But they are very hard and you need luck or a very good car. And always do headshots --> More rp.

PS: You always get 50 RP for rating the mission at the end.

Comment: Also you should note: IF you have a friend who is a higher level, get them to host a job out of your league (required level > your level) and get them to invite you. You'll get more RP because it's a harder mission (generally).

Comment: Will try in 17 hours. I am rank 12 atm and I plan to do the sms missions until rank 15 tomorrow. I don't get extreme fps so races aren't for me. If I rank up to 20 in 1-2 hours, this is the answer! (However, upvoted)

Comment: I tried it. I'm rank 15 atm. I tried it, but I only got to wave 3. I only got 500rp in the and ~250rp when I killed the enemies.

Comment: Play with 4 players survival. More enemies (more kills) and play in your crew (10% extra hp). I played a little nit capture Missions. And if your good you can get a lot rp there, too. But in the End its always play play play and be better then the rest.